# how to post multiple values using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have this code:

```
function Save(whichOne){
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var surname = $('#surname').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'SaveEntry.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: { "callFunc1": whichOne},
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
function Save(whichOne){
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var surname = $('#surname').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'SaveEntry.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: { "callFunc1": {whichOne, name, surname}},
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}
```

But it does not work. The problem is in this line:

```
data: { "callFunc1": {whichOne, name, surname}},
```

How do i post multiple values?

EDIT:
I am getting this error:
Warning: missing argument 2 for func1()

and i have this code:

```
if (isset($_POST['callFunc1'])) {
    echo func1($_POST['callFunc1']);
}
```

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: @martin Warning: missing argument 2 for func1()

Comment: you should pass the name value pairs then use the PHP to put the returns into the function.

Answer (score 3):

You need key value pairs unless you want to send JSON data:

```
data: { "callFunc1": whichOne, "name": name, "surname":surname}
```

Comment: i am getting this error: Warning: missing argument 2 for func1()

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to pass. It's either

`data: [whichOne, name, surname]` - that would be an array

or it's an object

`data: {
  "whichOne" : whichOne,
  "name" : name,
  "surname" : surname
}`